# link to specific anchor on a page with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

How does one go about linking to a specific id in a view with Laravel?

My controller:

```
public function services() {
 return View::make('services.custom_paint', array('pageTitle' => 'Custom Paint'))->with('default_title', $this->default_title);
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/custom_paint',  'PagesController@services');
```

I have tried to add `#id` to the route, to the controller, and even to the view's `URL::to`. Nothing seems to work.

I assumed that simply adding the id on to the URI would do the trick, but clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Can you show some code what have you tried for "add #id to the route, to the controller, and even to the view's URL::to"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// Controller
Route::get('/custom_paint', array('as' => 'custom_paint', 'uses' => 'PagesController@services'));

// View
<a href="{{ URL::route('custom_paint') }}#id">LINK</a>
```

Try this code ;) hope it works..

Comment: In a controller, this can be used as well (at least in Laravel 5.5): `return redirect()->to(route('custom_paint') . '#id');` (see also: stackoverflow.com/a/41606730/2286722)

Comment: @lieroes I tried your code but did not work in my case, can you have a look at my question? stackoverflow.com/q/62847193/12030116, I will upvote your both answer (in my question and this question), if this is solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass id to controller as parameter and need to point to correct result with #id

```
 <a href="{{ route('custom_paint',['id'=>'$id_value','#id']) }}">Try</a>
```

> I assume above will render as http://localhost/custom_paint/id=123#id

Or Just point to ID:

```
<a href="{{ route('custom_paint',['#id']) }}">Try</a>
```

> I assume above will render as http://localhost/custom_paint/#id

Answer (score -1):

Simply use

`<a href="{{ route('custom_paint') }}">LINK</a>`

if parameter is needed use it like this

`<a href="{{ route('custom_paint', 'param1') }}">LINK</a>`

[route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route)