# how can i add #somelink to laravel route

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to create a laravel route that links to a named anchor in a page. Could someone help with how to achieve that. Example: return Redirect::route('admin.articles.edit#somelink', $article->id);

In this case the route is in a controller which is redirecting back to the pages' comments section

Comment: possible duplicate of [link to specific anchor on a page with Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275667/link-to-specific-anchor-on-a-page-with-laravel)

Comment: which Laravel version are you using? Are you trying to put that in a Controller as a return of a method, in a View as a link or in the routes.php file as a new route?

Comment: I will appreciate all possible scenarios as i use them a lot in my applications. I'm using version 5.1

Comment: Use the answer provided from the duplicated link, and create a [macro](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#custom-macros) for this kind of links to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this and stumbled upon this older question.

The "possible duplicate" has an answer for the case where the link is created in a view (i.e. in html). It may not be immediately clear that this can also be used in returning a redirect route from a controller, as OP seemed to require (some years ago :).

At least in Laravel 5.5, it is possible to use this in the `redirect()->to()` function, e.g.:

```
return redirect()->to(
    route('admin.articles.edit', [$article->id]) . "#somelink"
);
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41606730/2286722) answer.